# How to add firebase ml kit in react native

Tags: react-native, firebase-mlkit

Currently I am using firebase in react native project

`"react-native-firebase": "5.6.0", in package.json file`

I use firebase ml kit

```
yarn add @react-native-firebase/app
yarn add @react-native-firebase/ml-vision
```

I installed react-native-firebase/app as above.

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "8.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/ml-vision": "7.2.2",
"react-native-firebase": "5.6.0" in package.json file
```

When using like this, the following error occurs
I think firebase is crashing
Is there any way to solve this?
Thanks for reading

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
  Program type already present: io.invertase.firebase.BuildConfig
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to mix together an old version of React Native Firebase (`"react-native-firebase": "5.6.0"`) along with a new version of React Native Firebase (`"@react-native-firebase/app": "8.2.0",`)

These are both completely different implementations of React Native Firebase and shouldn't be mixed; the `react-native-firebase` one being an old implementation that hasn't been supported for almost 2 years. Is there a reason you're trying to mix them?

The packages that start with `@react-native-firebase/*` are the correct ones to be using.

I'd recommend following these docs;

- https://rnfirebase.io/ (to get started)
- https://rnfirebase.io/ml/usage (to then integrate MLKit)

If you have any further issues with React Native Firebase I'd recommend raising an issue on the project's GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/new/choose) as this is the projects main support channel.